# Able to start module in terminal but not with PyCharm's run config

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, matrix-synapse

#### General Problem

I have already been able to run a certain module from the terminal. No I want to run the module with the run config on PyCharm. However it fails, even though I think I use the same configurations as in the terminal command. Or am I wrong?

The terminal command is:

```
lukas@lukas-XXXX:~/PycharmProjects/synapse$ source ./env/bin/activate
(env) lukas@lukas-XXXX:~/PycharmProjects/synapse$ python -m synapse.app.homeserver --config-path homeserver.yaml
```

For the run config I used the basic Python template and only changed the *Module name*, *Parameters* and *Working directory*. The Python interpreter should be the same as the environment that I have activated in the above command. Here is the config:
[image: Run Configuration]

Running this produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 185, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/home/lukas/PycharmProjects/synapse/synapse/app/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from synapse import python_dependencies  # noqa: E402
  File "/home/lukas/PycharmProjects/synapse/synapse/python_dependencies.py", line 29, in <module>
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'getLogger'
```

#### Used Module

The module is from the [synapse project](https://github.com/matrix-org/synapse) from matrix.org. The terminal command can be found [here](https://github.com/matrix-org/synapse#quick-start).

#### Assumptions and Observations I have so far

My assumption is that the `logging` module accessed in [`python_dependencies.py` line 29](https://github.com/matrix-org/synapse/blob/cbd82d0b2db069400b5d43373838817d8a0209e7/synapse/python_dependencies.py#L29) is resolved differently, depending on whether I start the module via the terminal or via PyCharm's run config. Using the terminal, it probably resolves to [Python's standard libary module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html). Using the *Run Config*, it  definitively uses synapse's [`logging` package](https://github.com/matrix-org/synapse/blob/cbd82d0b2db069400b5d43373838817d8a0209e7/tests/logging/__init__.py). Also, when using PyCharm to navigate to the `logging` package referenced to in `python_dependencies.py`, PyCharm gets me to synapse's custom `logging` module.

#### Question

The big question is: Why? Shouldn't my *Run Configuration* do exactly the same as my terminal command? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, somehow removing the marks at

- *Add content roots to `PYTHONPATH`* and
- *Add source roots to `PYTHONPATH`*

solved the issue.